# When hovering over link, want to move link towards the left without moving the border

Tags: html, css, hover, border, margin

I am trying to figure out if there's a way to move a link when hovering over it without moving its border. I want my links to move left but I don't want the border that I put to go with it. Here is a fiddle with what I am talking about. If you hover over any of the links, you see that the border moves with it, and I'd like to know if it's possible to not move the border.

And here is the code:

```css
.links {
  width: 240px;
  margin-left: -35px;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
}

.links a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(117, 117, 117, 0.3);
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
}

.links a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(207, 166, 255, 0.5);
  font-style: italic;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-weight: none;
  transition: 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.8s;
  -moz-transition: 0.8s;
  -o-transition: 0.8s;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a href="/">link</a>
  <a href="/">link</a>
  <a href="/">link</a>
  <a href="/">link</a>
  <a href="/">link</a>
</div>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can put a `<span>` tag in your link tag then apply the transition to the `<span>`

https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/n4Lsrv3k/2/

HTML

```
<div class="links">
  <a href="/"><span>link</span></a>
  <a href="/"><span>link</span></a>
  <a href="/"><span>link</span></a>
  <a href="/"><span>link</span></a>
  <a href="/"><span>link</span></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
span:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(207, 166, 255, 0.5);
  font-style: italic;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-weight: none;
  transition: 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.8s;
  -moz-transition: 0.8s;
  -o-transition: 0.8s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `.links a:hover` styling with the following code.

```
.links a:hover {
  font-style: italic;
  padding-right: 20px;
  transition: 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.8s;
  -moz-transition: 0.8s;
  -o-transition: 0.8s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your hover style, change `margin-right: 10px;` to `padding-right: 20px;`

Comment: Are you answering a question or asking one?

Answer (score 0):

Since Padding is spacing inside the border and Margin is for spacing outside the border, just change margin-right to padding-right (as Slawomir said)

Here is the fiddle with the change

[https://jsfiddle.net/092fd4hv/][1]

```
.links a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(207, 166, 255, 0.5);
  font-style: italic;
  padding-right: 20px;
  font-weight: none;
  transition: 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.8s;
  -moz-transition: 0.8s;
  -o-transition: 0.8s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a span tag is one way but you also can make a list from ul, border the li and animate the a when hover. Then you don't need to wrap every single element with the span tag.

```css
.links > li {
  width: 240px;
  margin-left: -35px;
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 8px;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(117, 117, 117, 0.3);
}

.links a:hover {
  font-style: italic;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-weight: none;
  transition: 0.8s;
  -webkit-transition: 0.8s;
  -moz-transition: 0.8s;
  -o-transition: 0.8s;
}
```

```html
<ul class="links">
  <li><a href="/">link</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">link</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">link</a></li>
  <li><a href="/">link</a></li>
</ul>
```

So you actually can remove several CSS code lines from .links a.